# Unable to retrieve objects from collection flask pymongo Flask-Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, flask, pymongo

I am trying to write a simple web-service which has one endpoint `/allTests`. The endpoint returns all the documents in a mongo collection. I am trying to do this with the [Flask-Pymongo](http://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)  library. But it returns an empty list of results even though there are a few documents in the particular mongo collection. Can anybody identify what I am doing wrong?

```
    import json
    from flask import Flask
    from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    from mabstats import config

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app=config.get_config(app)  #adds the MONGO_URI to app.config
    mongo = PyMongo(app)

    @app.route('/health')
    def healthcheck():
        return json.dumps({'value':'Healthy!'})

    @app.route('/allTests')
    def gettests():
        collection_name=app.config['MONGO_ARCHIVE_COLLECTION'] #name of collection
        print "Collection",collection_name
        collection=getattr(mongo.db,collection_name)
        print "Collection Object",collection

        results=[item for item in collection.find()]
        return json.dumps(results)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Output:[image]

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: The specific problem is that the response is an empty list [ ]. I am unable to retrieve the results (document from the collection) even though everything seems to be correct in my code as far as I can tell? Is this the correct way to use the PyMongo module? I'm just going off of the documentation but it isn't working for me. @dirn

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to retrieve the results"? Are you getting an error message? If so, you should provide the traceback.

Comment: Nope that's the weird thing. Absolutely no error. It's running fine.  The output I see is an empty list with no results. @dirn

Comment: Are you sure that you have data in the collection?